# if all my views are passed a strongly typed viewdata, if they have a baseviewdata class, can I set a property in onexecuting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want all my views to inherit from a baseview data so I can set some shared properties that all my views will need.

Can I set some properties in OnExecuting so I don't have to do it for all Actions?

I want to then display the string value of the property in all my view pages.

If yes, how can I do this?  I need to hook into the base view data somehow?

so i'll have:

**public MyViewData : ViewData
{
}**

And I need one for generics also?

Comment: Where are you instantiating your instances?

Comment: instances of what?  The strongly typed viewdata's are instantiated in the actions. but i could change that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to make a generic helper method that instantiates the ViewData classes and sets the properties.
You can then call this method in your actions to create the ViewData instances.

For example:

```
static TData CreateData<TData>() where TData : BaseViewData, new() {
    TData retVal = new TData();
    //Set properties...
    return retVal;
}
```